# Flutter update 8/1/17 broke Android

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Is anyone having any issues on Android with the flutter update on August 1st? I updated yesterday and ever since I have not been able to run on Android emulators while iOS is fine. I get the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl.cc(161)] Could not wrap onscreen surface.
```

flutter doctor results below:

```
[✓] Flutter (on Mac OS X 10.12.5 16F73, locale en-US, channel alpha)
• Flutter at /Users/kyles/flutter
• Framework revision bbcfb8d51a (3 days ago), 2017-08-01 14:50:29 -0700
• Engine revision f2af347363
• Tools Dart version 1.25.0-dev.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/kyles/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-26, build-tools 26.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 8.3.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 8.3.3, Build version 8E3004b
    • ios-deploy 1.9.1
    • CocoaPods version 1.2.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2.1)
    • Flutter plugin version 16.0
    • Dart plugin version 172.3544.34

[✓] Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)
```

Also, I transferred the code to my laptop which has the previous version of flutter installed and it compiles and runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed**

Eric Seidel from Google explained this has been fixed, but has not been pushed down to the alpha channel yet. In the meantime, it is possible to just use 'flutter channel master' to switch to the latest code with the fix